# Android setlayout visibility on button click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

In the following code on click of the button i want to hide the relative layout `rl1` and show `rl2` but my app crashes down after on button click.What am i doing wrong

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/rl1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/welcome_1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:paddingTop="360dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/button1" />

     </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl2"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
     android:background="@drawable/menu_2"
        ></RelativeLayout>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Java code

```
public class mockupsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


 // ImageButton img1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ImageView img1 =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // your code here
   //       Toast.makeText(TouchpointmockupsActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LinearLayout rl1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl1);
            rl1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            LinearLayout rl2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl2);
            rl2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });





}
}
```

Comment: You should read your logcat, it will tell you what youve done wrong. Or at least post it, so others can see the stacktrace. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `LinearLayout`  to `RelativeLayout` in your code. You might be getting a classcastException.

Edit:
Change OnClick method as below

```
        RelativeLayout rl1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl1);
        rl1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        RelativeLayout rl2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl2);
        rl2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: check the edit. The layout has RelativeLayout but you are casting it to LinearLayout

Comment: @Rajeev Hes talking about rl1, and rl2. You have them as relevative layouts, yet cast them to linear layouts.

Comment: Not sure. make the relativelayout visible to check whether background is visible in normal cases. Check if the menu_2 is present. Also if you want the invisible layout to not take space in the layout you better use View.GONE instead of View.INVISIBLE